# Hashicorp Vault returns Bearer error="insufficient_scope" description="The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token."

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to use Hashicorp Vault as an OIDC Provider.  My app is a simple spring boot rest app and I am trying to test it with Postman. I want to use Oauth2 authorization.  This is a learning exercise and not something that needs to go into production, however, I still want to follow "Production Best Practices" as far as possible.

### Spring Boot

My Spring Boot APP running on https://dev.home.my.net:9780/ has the following configured in the  POM.xml file.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The application.yml file includes this:

```yaml
spring:
   security:
        oauth2:
            resourceserver:
                jwt:
                    issuer-uri: https://utils.home.my.net:9790/v1/identity/oidc/provider/dummyapi-provider
```

My SecurityFilterChain Bean looks like this:

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .requestMatchers(ELEVATED_WHITELIST).hasAnyAuthority("SCOPE_MYADMIN", "SCOPE_MYELEVATED")
                .requestMatchers(WHITELIST).hasAnyAuthority("SCOPE_MYADMIN", "SCOPE_MYELEVATED", "SCOPE_MYUSER")
                .requestMatchers(OPEN_ACCESS).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            );
            http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

        return http.build();
    }
```

- ELEVATED_WHITELIST = is a list of GET or POST mappings that I want to grant access only to MYADMIN and MYELEVATED
- WHITELIST = is a list of GET or POST mappings that I want to grant access only to MYADMIN, MYELEVATED and also MYUSER
- OPEN_ACCESS = All access to any endpoints not in the above lists

### Hashicorp Vault

My Vault configuration - *and this is where I believe I have less that the little understanding I have elsewhere* - has been configured as follows:

1. I have enabled a *userpass* Auth method.
2. Inside that userpass I have just one user *my_admin_user*
3. I have an entity (Still under the access tab) also called *my_admin_user* with a reference to the user I created in the userpass Auth Method point earlier.
4. I created a Group called MYADMIN still under Access.
5. I have made *my_admin_user* a member of that group.
6. Under OIDC Provider I have an Application called *dummyapi* where I get the Client ID and the Client Secret from.  I also use a *dummyapi-key* that I set up while following a tutorial somewhere.
7. I created an Assignment called MYADMIN (the same name as the group and the scope I wish to use in the dummy app). Inside this Assignment I select my *my_admin_user* user as well as my MYADMIN group
8. I jumped to Scopes and created a MYADMIN scope which simple has the following JSON in it

```json
{
  "username": {{identity.entity.name}},
  "groups": {{identity.entity.groups.names}}
}
```

9. I created a Provider *dummyapi-provider* and selected the Scope that I had just created under the Supported scopes search field.
10. I don't think there is anything else that I need to configure here for now.

### Postman

I am trying 2 requests.  1 works and the other one does not!  This is actually the issue and I think it has to do with scopes.

My configuration for both requests is the same

```
Authorization Type: Oauth 2.0
Callback URL: https://dev.home.my.net:9780/
Auth Url: https://utils.home.my.net:9790/ui/vault/identity/oidc/provider/dummyapi-provider/authorize
Access Token Url: https://utils.home.my.net:9790/v1/identity/oidc/provider/dummyapi-provider/token
Client ID: Copied from the Vault Applications->dummyapi
Client Secret: Copied from the Vault Applications->dummyapi
Scope: **openid**  I read that I have to use openid here however when testing againse Azure I could put other scopes in this place and they were honored in the SecurityFilterChain by the .hasAnyAuthority lines.
```

#### 1st Get

https://dev.home.my.net:9780/dummyapi/listItems is part of WHITELIST

Once I have authenticated and received a token in the response.  I use the ID token part of what was returned in postman and I am able to see the expected results.  In otherwords I receive a Status: 200 OK

#### 2nd Get

https://dev.home.my.net:9780/dummyapi/listPrivateItems is part of ELEVATED_WHITELIST.

I can authenticate successfully here.  However I receive a Status: 403 Forbidden message returned and when inspecting the headers I came across this in the response:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="insufficient_scope", error_description="The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token.", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"
```

I thought that I had configured the scope in Vault to be MYADMIN which would correspond to what the SecurityFilterChain is configured to allow.  However because of how it is behaving I don't think this scope is behaving as I expect.  So after I have authenticated with the scope of openid, where does the scope get set for authorization with the app.  If I look in the token I don't see anything speaking about scopes for either request.

So after all that I am wanting to know how and where do I set the scope in postman, the vault or dummyapi's SecurityFilterChain so that I can have different users access different resources?  If you got this far I owe you a drink!

Here are some of the links I have been pouring over - there are a few more but these have mostly helped me get this far.

- [Vault as an OIDC Provider](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/auth-methods/oidc-identity-provider)
- [How to set up OIDC on Vault](https://devops-fu.org/vault/2022/05/26/set-up-oidc-on-vault.html)
- [Vault ACL Policies](https://github.com/jeffsanicola/vault-policy-guide)
- [Vaults OIDC Provider](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/concepts/oidc-provider)

### EDIT #1 - Added the Token JSON Payload

Adding the Id Token (which I said I was using above) to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and I see that jwt.io tells me that there is an invalid signature.

#### ID Token

```json
{
  "at_hash": "3Rz7cznliUSLrB2St7RS5g",
  "aud": "6Am2NXPeM8J6DaV4sX0JMPUZBsH32L78",
  "c_hash": "Tc9d3_evG3diE2YGXtCGSg",
  "exp": 1683955132,
  "iat": 1683868732,
  "iss": "https://utils.home.my.net:9790/v1/identity/oidc/provider/dummyapi-provider",
  "namespace": "root",
  "sub": "25328fea-cc19-f517-83f8-5eee3bbaf5e0"
}
```

#### Access Token

[jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) also tells me that the signature is invalid and this payload cannot be read.  It looks like all binary characters.

#### Edit #2

It seems as though the request I was making in the first case (1st Get) - that I assumed was in the WHITELIST is not actually part of the WHITELIST and is being allowed by the .requestMatchers("/**").authenticated() part of the SecurityFilterChain.

This means that my token does not contain any scopes, which is what it looks like.  So how then to I add a scope to my token?

Comment: Would you add the JSON payload of an access token (not the token string, just its payload, use a tool like https://jwt.io)? It's likely that your authorization server puts roles in a different claim than scope, in which case you'll have to configure an authorities converter.

Comment: If the access token is not a JWT, then you must configure your resource-server with introspection ("opaque token"). Look at OpenID configuration (or documentation) for introspection endpoint. If you can't find one, you could build a custom Introspector using user-info endpoint.